# Creating a frequency histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r

Hi I am relatively new to R.  I am struggling with what seems like it should be a relatively simple task- I am trying to make a frequency histogram using ggplot2 from a subset of data from a longer dataframe.
Here is an example of the data structure us in the picture attached
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIwQv.png

The data is from a survey where 0 means not selected and 1 means it was selected. There are numeric in the original dataset I want a histogram of the frequency in which each variable was selected.  The column variables on the x-axis and frequency counts on the y-axis.  I have various subsets like this within a dataframe and I would like each to subset to how their own graph.

I first subset the columns of interest
new dataset <-subset(df, select = c(WAB_R, WAB_B, BDAE, PNT))
When I checked the class it was dataframe and no longer numeric

I tried to use as.numeric to convert it back to a numeric, but with no luck
I could use some guidance in how to structure the data to then obtain a histogram.

Thanks Carla

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this approach using `tidyverse` functions. You have to reshape to long selecting the desired variables. Here the code using `ggplot2` for the final plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code 1
df %>% select(c(WAB_R, WAB_B, BDAE, PNT)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value))+
  geom_histogram(stat = 'count',aes(fill=name),
                 position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+
  labs(fill='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
df %>% select(c(WAB_R, WAB_B, BDAE, PNT)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(value)))+
  geom_histogram(stat = 'count',aes(fill=name),
                 position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+
  labs(fill='Variable')+xlab('value')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, WAB_R = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), WAB_B = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), BDAE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), PNT = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Both of those codes worked.  Now I am interested in just the 1s or yes to be included in the graph.  Could I just add code to remove the 0s or No?

Comment: Thank you! Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: So I have one more question....I would like to order the variables in descending order. I tried using the reorder function in this way   ggplot(aes(x= reorder(value, -n, y = n))) but this produced an error message.  Any advice here?